macOS 15.1 has iPhone Mirroring, but how do I "rotate" the iPhone?
I can't find a way to do it, even though it seems like a trivial thing to do for mirroring. How can it be done?

It auto-rotates if an app requests landscape mode, but you can't then use the app switcher to switch to Safari and keep landscape mode active. Seems like an oversight.

or if I am watching YouTube and hope to flip it landscape mode and watch it full screen. It seems like I have to physically rotate the phone instead
